# Need to insert records to oracle table for scheduling

Tags: oracle, date, insert, schedule

Please help me to solve this requirement. There is from date ,to date and schedule type(Daily , weekly, monthly, annually) as parameters. I need to insert rows to oracle table for scheduling using mentioned 3 parameters.

```
Eg-  
        from date=01/01/2021
        to date = 25/01/2021
        schedule type=Daily
```

Then table should insert following rows

```
    Scheduled Dates
    01/01/2021
    02/01/2021
    03/01/2021
    .
    24/01/2021
    25/01/2021
```

---

```
Eg-    

  when from date=01/01/2021
    to date = 25/01/2021
    schedule type=Weekly
```

Then table should insert following rows

```
Scheduled Dates
01/01/2021
08/01/2021
15/01/2021
22/01/2021
```

Comment: You can check out [dbms-scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbms-scheduler?tab=Newest) tag

Comment: Hi I need https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_LIHBDFVF9IUU6AFZB4H6NVLWL.html kind of solution, This is perfect , But unfortunately I have oracle 12c which doesn't support sql macro

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it is about the *row generator* technique as you should generate *number of rows* depending on certain input parameters. Here's one option.

Target table:

```
SQL> create table t_schedule (datum date, type varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

Procedure which will generate rows; for simplicity, quarterly schedules are separated from weekly and daily ones:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_schedule
  2    (par_date_from in date, par_date_to in date, par_type in varchar2)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    if par_type in ('daily', 'weekly') then
  6       insert into t_schedule (datum, type)
  7       select par_date_from + (case when par_type = 'weekly' then 7 else 1 end) * (level - 1) as datum,
  8              par_type
  9       from dual
 10       connect by level <= ceil((par_date_to - par_date_from + 1) /
 11                                 case when par_type = 'weekly' then 7 else 1 end);
 12    elsif par_type in ('monthly', 'quarterly', 'annually') then
 13       insert into t_schedule (datum, type)
 14       select add_months(par_date_from, case when par_type = 'monthly'   then 1
 15                                             when par_type = 'quarterly' then 3
 16                                             when par_type = 'annually'  then 12
 17                                        end * (level - 1)) as datum,
 18              par_type
 19       from dual
 20       connect by level <= ceil(months_between(par_date_to, par_date_from) /
 21                                        case when par_type = 'monthly'   then 1
 22                                             when par_type = 'quarterly' then 3
 23                                             when par_type = 'annually'  then 12
 24                                        end);
 25    end if;
 26  end;
 27  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing: daily schedule:

```
SQL> exec p_schedule(date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-25', 'daily');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Testing: weekly schedule:

```
SQL> exec p_schedule(date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-25', 'weekly');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Testing: quaraterly schedule:

```
SQL> exec p_schedule(date '2021-01-01', date '2021-10-25', 'quarterly');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result: distinguish rows by the **type**:

```
SQL> select * from t_schedule order by type, datum;

DATUM      TYPE
---------- ----------
01.01.2021 daily
02.01.2021 daily
03.01.2021 daily
04.01.2021 daily
05.01.2021 daily
06.01.2021 daily
07.01.2021 daily
08.01.2021 daily
09.01.2021 daily
10.01.2021 daily
11.01.2021 daily
12.01.2021 daily
13.01.2021 daily
14.01.2021 daily
15.01.2021 daily
16.01.2021 daily
17.01.2021 daily
18.01.2021 daily
19.01.2021 daily
20.01.2021 daily
21.01.2021 daily
22.01.2021 daily
23.01.2021 daily
24.01.2021 daily
25.01.2021 daily
01.01.2021 quarterly
01.04.2021 quarterly
01.07.2021 quarterly
01.10.2021 quarterly
01.01.2021 weekly
08.01.2021 weekly
15.01.2021 weekly
22.01.2021 weekly

33 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi I really appreciate your answer, And also can you please tell me how to generate quarterly?

Comment: Done; have a look.

Comment: "Thank you" on Stack Overflow is best said by upvoting/accepting useful answers, @TDApower.

Comment: Hi it's great if you can also add monthly and annually to the procedure

Comment: Added monthly and annually options as well.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your support

Comment: @TDApower, the best way to say thank you is to accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: @Littlefoot, really cool solution, as always. Anyone might learn a lot from your posts, myself included  ;)

Comment: Thank you, @Roberto. I enjoy reading your answers as well :)